# ASP.NET Textbox cannot retain value set by JavaScript inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

This may be a duplicate question but none I found working for me.

I have 10-20 divs representing categories. Each div have rel attribute containing id of category.
All of the code is inside an UpdatePanel.

I want to update selected categories (clicked div) ids in the database. There is an asp:TextBox and an asp:Button clicking on which I will set selected value in textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="lbSelectedCategories" CssClass="lbSelectedCategories" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

For this, I added following jQuery code:

```
$(".area-interest-list li").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        copySelectedCategoriesToLabel();
});

function copySelectedCategoriesToLabel() {
    var selectedCategoryIds = [];

    $(".area-interest-list").find('li').get().forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        var selectedCategoryId = $(item).attr('rel');

        if ($(item).attr('class') == 'active') {
            selectedCategoryIds.push(selectedCategoryId);
        }
    });

    // Remove last ,
    var strSelectedCategoryIds = selectedCategoryIds.join(',');

    $(".lbSelectedCategories").text(strSelectedCategoryIds);
}
```

I tried both text() and val() function.
I can see the values are being set properly in the textobx, but when I try to read on Button_Click, I get empty value.

```
string lbSelectedCategories = lbSelectedCategories.Text;
```

May be postback on UpdatePanel is loosing textobx values.

I read that labels don't retain their values, but for me, textbox or hidden field both are not retaining their values.

**Update Panel Code**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelCategories" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="ti-close"></span></button>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveCategory" class="btn btn-style-red" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveCategory_Click"></asp:Button>
            <h4>Areas Of Interest</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterResourceCategory" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeaterResourceCategory_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div class="area-interest-list">
                        <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="" rel='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>' id="liSelected" runat="server">
                        <span class="icon-cloud-computing" runat="server" id="spIcon" rel='<%# Eval("IsSelected") %>'></span>
                        <p runat="server" id="pText"><%# Eval("CategoryName") %></p>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <li class="" rel='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>' id="liSelected" runat="server">
                        <span class="icon-cloud-computing" runat="server" id="spIcon" rel='<%# Eval("IsSelected") %>'></span>
                        <p runat="server" id="pText"><%# Eval("CategoryName") %></p>
                    </li>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
            </div>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:TextBox ID="lbSelectedCategories" CssClass="lbSelectedCategories" runat="server" style="width:1px;height:1px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Button Code**

```
protected void btnSaveCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddSelectedCategories();
}

private void AddSelectedCategories()
{
    UserInfo userInfo = MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser;

    string[] arSelectedCategories = lbSelectedCategories.Text.Split(',');

    if (arSelectedCategories.Length > 0)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            for (int i = 0; i < arSelectedCategories.Length; i++)
            {
                string sql = @"insert into sometable(UserID, ResourceCategoryID) values(" + userInfo.UserID + "," + arSelectedCategories[i] + ")";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using the `IsPostBack` check when changing textbox values from code behind?

Comment: And could you add `UpdatePanel` and `Button` codes as well?

Comment: I'm not changing TextBox value from codebehind, just reading it. The value is set using JavaScript but empty in code behind when I try to read

Comment: Code added @SelimYıldız

Comment: I have tested your code and I can get text of `lbSelectedCategories`without any problem in button click.  I think you set text of this label somewhere else too for example in page_load, is that possible?

Comment: No Selim, I've checked thoroughly and not setting its value anywhere :(

Comment: I found the error, instead of text() function, I had to use val()